# Importing second model just duplicates the first one

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode, import, .fbx

I have two models, the first one imports fine and I would like to import the second one to scale it to be the same size as the first. The issue arises when I try to import the second model, as soon as I click "Import FBX" it just copies the first model, nothing in the outliner or elsewhere to hint that the new one is in the project.

TLDR: I go to file > import > FBX, then see title happens, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome. Your question is a little vague. Could you improve it with some details?